# DeprecationWarning: remove_friend is deprecated. await coro(*args, **kwargs)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted to make self bot and command to unfriend someone but when I use it removes friends but gives me a warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: remove_friend is deprecated.
  await coro(*args, **kwargs)
```

Code:

```
for i in client.user.friends:   
    try: 
        await i.remove_friend()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to remove it from console

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.7, all user related endpoints are deprecated and awaiting their subsequent removal in version 2.0 of `discord.py`. You can currently safely ignore this warning but be aware that when 2.0 will be released, if you decide to upgrade, your code wont work anymore.

You can add this shebang if you are running Linux to prevent warning in console

`#!/usr/bin/env python -W ignore::DeprecationWarning`

If you run Windows, the equivalent is `python file_name.py -W ignore::DeprecationWarning`

If that does not work you can use this quick and dirty hack (it will hide any warning so be careful). Put below code at the top of your files.

```
def warn(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

import warnings
warnings.warn = warn
```

Comment: i mean it print in console and it disturbs me